# Problem with creating ROS in Fuerte

Tags: ros, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently installed ROS Fuerte on my laptop ( still have ROS electric on it). When I tery to creat a workspace, I get the following error:

turtlebot@turtlebot03:~$ rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/rosws", line 52, in 
import rosinstall.rosws_cli
ImportError: No module named rosws_cli

Does anyone have any idea what might be source of the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72550/problem-with-creating-ros-in-fuerte/) by [z.bagheri63](https://answers.ros.org/users/5896/z.bagheri63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-09-29**:
Fuerte is already old. Consider updating to a newer distro (aka Hydro) so that you can have more people able to help you. Just a wild guess, is it better after running: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update python-rosinstall` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try swapping your active distro by calling source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [Jman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11456/jman/) with karma: 31 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0